# Spring Bean Validation with Hibernate: validation not happening on update

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a class defined as follows:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

public class Game {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "title")
    String title;
    ...
```

However, when I execute the following test, no validation exception is thrown:

```
@Test(expected = ConstraintViolationException.class)
public void thatExistingGameGivenBlankTitleCannotBeSaved(){
    Game game = new Game("SimCity 2000");
    gameDAO.save(game);
    game.setTitle(" "); //game.setTitle(null) doesn't work either
    gameDAO.save(game);
}
```

How can I make the validator trigger when saving an already persisted object? Preferably through Java configuration.

My validation dependencies:

```
<!-- validation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does `@NotBlank` check white space?

Comment: Validations are generally (and should be) done on the command bean.

Comment: Thanks, could you please direct me to some documentation on how to do this?

Comment: [1](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/), [2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html), [3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/) is a basic full-fledged example.

Comment: Answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12146298/1391249) question say much about validations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis [Api](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html) says: Validate that the annotated string is not null or empty. The difference to NotEmpty is that trailing whitespaces are getting ignored.

Comment: @CarlosDanielGadeaOmelchenko Your gameDAO.save() is calling hibernate ORM?

Comment: @Tiny There's nothing wrong in setting constraints on the domain model.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch gameDAO extends JpaRespository. Spring creates a proxy of GameDAO that handles persistence via Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Your JPA implementation has to integrate bean validation. If you're using Hibernate this will happen automatically by putting the validation provider in the class path. If not read [10.1.3. JPA](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-integration.html#d0e5187). Given your tags I assume you're using JPA/Hibernate and it should work.

I don't know what `gameDAO.save()` is calling on your JPA implementation. Hibernate's integration is [event based](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-integration.html#validator-checkconstraints-orm-hibernateevent). If your `save()` is none of these events there will be no validation by default:

- PreInsertEvent
- PreUpdateEvent
- PreDeleteEvent