# Spring MVC - validation for comparing two fields

Tags: java, validation, rest, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring MVC application and have a question about spring validation. First, I have this action in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody
Employee employeeCreate(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeModelCreate objModel) throws Exception {
  ...
}
```

And this is my `EmployeeModelCreate` class:

```
public class EmployeeModelCreate implements Serializable {
    ...
    @NotBlank(message = "...")
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "...")
    private String confirmPassword;
    ...

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

Now, I want to have validation for comparing `password` and `confirmPassword`. This validation should be check equality of these two fields. How can I do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a custom validation class, for this you need to implement the `Validator` interface, then you can use it manually, or bind it to the Spring MVC controller, using the `@InitBinder` annotation.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146298/spring-mvc-how-to-perform-validation) may contain other useful information.

Comment: Thank your for your replay @meskobalazs. Your suggested link is very good and helped me a lot. Thanks again.