# what i need to write in else part in the following code?

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping("/insert")  
         public String insertEmpDetails(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp) {
          if (emp != null) 
          empService.insertEmpDetails(emp);  
          return "redirect:/getList";
         }
```

Please tell me what to write in else part.I was trying for that but i am not getting

Answer (score 0):

Make `employeeId` as a required param to serve the request by this `RequestMapping` then you don't need to write else part because `Employee` model will never be `null` in that case. It must have at least `employeeId`.

*Note:* Make it `POST` request.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", params = "employeeId", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public String insertEmpDetails(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp) {
          empService.insertEmpDetails(emp);  
          return "redirect:/getList";
}
```

In other way you can validate the model and redirect to form page back with validation error messages.

Sample:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", params = "employeeId", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public String insertEmpDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your custom error messages");
        return "<<back to form page without redirection>>";
    }else {
        empService.insertEmpDetails(emp);  
        return "redirect:/getList";
    }
}
```

Read more about [Spring - Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Read a post on [Spring MVC : How to perform validation ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146298/spring-mvc-how-to-perform-validation)