# Making request to @Valid

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, jsr

I'm developping spring-boot application, I need to validate user information before checking other information. This is a snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ceateCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody User user){ 
      myService.create(user);
}
```

When the user comes from another route **/create-sp-user**, I have to re-valid the user:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-sp-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ceateCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody User user){ 
      user.setSp(true);
      // I tried @Valid user without success
      // In my User class if sp = true the field telNumber is mandatory   
      myService.create(user);
}
```

Would you have  any ideas ?

Best regards

Comment: You can easily write your own custom validator as there is no default valitator that checks for required fields based on the value of others.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want. what's the user structure coming from the client? Or is it, that you want to validate the user **after** you've set sp = true? In that case, you might want to write your custom validator as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146298/spring-mvc-how-to-perform-validation - the @valid annotation checks it **before** any code is executed in the controller.

Comment: Thanks @Dominik yes I have to validate the user after set sp to true

Answer (score 0):

Like Dominik said, @Valid annotation validates the object before any code is executed in the controller

If you want to validate the object inside the method you should use custom validator.

Implement `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and call the `validate` method inside controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-sp-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ceateCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result){ 
      user.setSp(true);
      CustomValidator customValidator = new CustomValidator();
      customValidator.validate(user, result);

      if (result.hasErrors()){
        //do something
      } else {
        myService.create(user);
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Janar I tried you solution but I have all the time 0 errors.

Comment: perhaps you implemented the validator wrongly? please post your validator code.

Comment: Hi @Janar I'm working with @Olivier this is the validator class `public class UserValidator implements Validator {
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserValidator.class);
    @Override    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return userInfo.class.equals(clazz);
    }
    @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        User userInfo = (User) target;
 ... 
         // Phone number
  if (StringUtils.isBlank(userInfo.getPhoneNumber())) {
   errors.rejectValue("phoneNumber", "phoneNumber[required]", "Failed");
  }   ..
 }
}`

Comment: The `supports` method seems to be wrongly implemented - you should check if `User.class.equals(clazz);`. Also try debugging the validate method - is it getting called, is phoneNumber blank when you call it?

Comment: When I call @Valid User it works but when I call @Valid on class wrapper like  `class testWrapper {  @Valid private UserInfo u1 , @Valid private UserInfo u2}`

Comment: You need to validate with your custom validator