# Using validators with a class that is not persisted in the database

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

as part of a website i'm building using Spring Boot, I receive input via Thymeleaf form. To validate the input i have created a class and annotated its fields:

```
package com.bank.domain;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NewClass {

    //if record is active/inactive (hidden)
    @Column
    private boolean active=true;

    //bank of account holder
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max =3)
    private String banknum;

    //branch
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max =3)
    private String branchnum;

    // account number
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max =10)
    private String accountnum;

    // number / range of numbers of Check
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=9, fraction=0)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED INT(9) not null",nullable=false)
    private String fromchecknum;

    // number / range of numbers of Check
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer=9, fraction=0)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED INT(9) not null",nullable=false)
    private String tochecknum;
}
```

because I have debug turned on, i see that sql output in dumped to the log, even though there is no table for this class in the database.
I want to not waste resources on the SQL queries or whatever they are, since there is no underlying table, just a class with fields that have validators.

So my question is -
is it possible to just use a regular class and also employing the various annotation such as  `@Size`, `@Min`, `@NotNull`, `@Digits`, etc?

Comment: Why do you have `@Column` annotation if it is not persisted?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/12149331/3530898

Comment: @holmis83   that was part of the question.- . if its ok to just remove those annotations and still use validation annotations (though I'm not persisting to the database)

Comment: @AmitKBist  this partly answers , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your class it seems that the use of `@Column` is the only thing dealing with persistence. Do you want to have that annotation? If you look at the package structure, `@column` is is persistence package and the validation related annotations reside in `javax.validation` and not in the persistence package.
Bean validations (JSR303) like `@NotNull`, etc can be used even when your bean is not `@Entity`. I think that was your question, right?

Comment: So just by removing the @column and using a JSR303 library  I'll still be able to use validations without the persistence overhead?

thanks,  I will give this a try...

Comment: @Dror I think yes, you should be. Let's know if you run into any problems