# Input validation with JSR-303 & Spring Boot (Rest Controller): HTML response instead of JSON

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-restcontroller

I followed these two links/tutorials:

a) [Spring MVC: How to perform validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146298/spring-mvc-how-to-perform-validation/12149331#12149331)

b) https://g00glen00b.be/validating-the-input-of-your-rest-api-with-spring/

It works fine except for one thing. Eventhough my controller is annotated with @RestController the response I get is HTML, unlike the JSON response shown in the tutorial.

Questions:

1. Which component/bean is the "culprit" which builds and returns the HTML response?
2. How to make it return a response body instead of a view?
3. How to override this component with a custom one?

Best! Pawel

Comment: Ok, I found the answer to 1):

DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver

2 and 3) You implement an own ExceptionResolver annotated with @ControllerAdvice

Comment: Did you send the `Content-Type: application/json` header? The default Spring exception handler will format your response to either HTML/JSON/... depending on the output you want.

Comment: Cool, I got a response from g00glen00b her or himself ;-) After all I implemented my own ExceptionResolver (which is also described in your tutorial) to handle it. And it returns a response body, so - problem solved! Thanks